# Set State Failing After Second Render of Function Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have what seems to be a really odd issue with a react function component.

For brevity my code look like:

```
const Clients = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    loading: true,
    entities: [],
    editing: null,
  });

  const ajax = useAjax(api.scopes);
  const errorHandler = useErrorHandler();

  useEffect(() => {
    ajax.get(`${api.endpoint}/clients`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
        throw new HttpError(response);
      })
      .then((json) => setState({
        ...state,
        entities: json,
        loading: false,
      }))
      .catch(errorHandler);
  }, []);

  const handleSelect = (entity) => {
    console.log({
      entity,
    });
    setState({
      ...state,
      editing: entity,
    });
  };

  console.log('hello world!');

  const { loading, entities, editing } = state;

  return (
    loading ? <LinearProgress /> : (
      <>
         <TableComponent entities={entities} onSelect={handleSelect} />
         <EditingComponent 
            entity={editing}
            open={!!editing}
            onClose={() => setState({ ...state, editing: null })}
          />
      </>
    )
  );
};

export default Clients;
```

The `<TableComponent />` always works as expected and the event handler is always called with the correct entity passed.

What is not happening is that the editing component only opens the first time the component is mounted (case 1). At this stage the editing component opens with the correct info, and continues to do so whichever row is clicked.

After this, if I navigate away from this component (React Router 6.4.2) and then come back to it (case 2). The entities still load, but the `handleSelect` function fails to update the state and nothing happens when a row is clicked (it is called however).

The `useAjax` hook is to support azure msal and has been working perfectly since written and the network trace doesn't show any issue accessing the API.

React is version 18.2.0 if that is relevant.

The `useEffect` function is called in all cases and the entities are set correctly.

The `console.log` in the `handleSelect` always shows the correct `entity` as selected in the table.

The second `console.log` ('hello world!') gets called when the page loads (in both cases) then only in the first case when a row is selected.

Using React Dev Tools it shows that the state is simply not updated in the second case.

What is really confusing me is why there is any difference between case 1 and case 2, as it doesn't matter if I navigate to a page where the component tree is doesn't include the above and I assume m references to the component are dropped.  I suspect this is a misunderstanding that I have about how React and/or React Router are working.

Trying to Google the issue mainly seems to return issues about the state not updating immediately after it is set - which I am pretty sure is not the case.

Comment: can you provide a sandbox to this issue, that will be helpful to debug

Comment: If you believe routing/navigation is relevant to the issue then please [edit] the post to include all the relevant code you suspect is involved with the issue. Can you update the post to include a more complete [mcve] enough for us to reproduce the issue ourselves? Could you try also creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Answer (score 0):

It's a long explanation but you should use setState like this (in your case):

```
setState(previousState => ({
  ...previousState ,
  editing: entity,
}));
```